# Check for any values in set

Tags: python, set

Suppose I have the following set:

```
things = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
```

I would like to find out if either `foo` *or* `bar` exists in the set. I've tried:

```
>>> 'foo' in things or 'bar' in things
True
```

This works, but is there not a more Pythonic way of doing this check without having multiple `or` statements? I can't find anything in the standard Python set operations that can achieve this. Using  `{'foo', 'bar'} <= things` checks for *both*, but I want to check for either of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you're using sets, you could use:

```
if {'foo','bar'} & things:
    ...
```

`&` indicates set intersection, and the intersection will be truthy whenever it is nonempty.

Answer (score 6):

Talking sets, what you actually want to know is if the intersection is nonempty:

```
if things & {'foo', 'bar'}:
    # At least one of them is in
```

And there is always any():

```
any(t in things for t in ['foo', 'bar'])
```

Which is nice in case you have a long list of things to check. But for just two things, I prefer the simple `or`.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the intersection of the sets:

```
things = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}

things.intersection({'foo', 'other'})
# {'foo'}

things.intersection('none', 'here')
#set
```

So, as empty sets are falsy in boolean context, you can do:

```
if things.intersection({'foo', 'other'}):
    print("some common value")
else:
    print('no one here')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint):

```
if not things.isdisjoint({'foo', 'bar'}):
    ...
```

Or [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection):

```
if things.intersection({'foo', 'bar'}):
    ...
```

Or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(thing in things for thing in ['foo', 'bar']):
    ...
```

Or stick with `or`, because very often that's actually the most readable solution:

```
if 'foo' in things or 'bar' in things:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
things = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
any([i in things for i in ['foo', 'bar']])
```